# Using JSON with Dygraph and datetime

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, dygraphs

I'm using Dygraph and jQuery as below:

```
$.getJSON('/myurl/for/jsondata', function(data) {
  g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("demodiv"), data, {});
});
```

The response datas are as below:

```
[[1372951380.0, 82.31065525957484], [1372951440.0, 85.25771431214908], [1372951500.0, 81.12563963030715], [1372951560.0, 80.87068966263206], [1372951620.0, 80.18137775897438], [1372951680.0, 81.46331467662664], [1372951740.0, 77.4216130457947]]
```

My trouble is dygraph doesn't seem to take timestamps as date. It shows number for legend. I tried to use ValueFormatter, ValueParser, and AxisLabelFormatter but with no success (maybe I did wrong?)

Does someone know how to enable datetime without walk in all data and convert timestamps manually ?

Comment: dygraphs is expecting a Date object in the first column, not a timestamp. Do the conversion (perhaps using $.map) and it should work. If you want to use valueFormatter and friends, you'll get better help by posting a link using dygraphs.com/fiddle.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I wasn't aware that Dygraphs support JSON at all either?

Comment: Dygraphs supports native arrays... http://dygraphs.com/data.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
var utcSeconds = 1372951380;
var d = new Date(0); // The 0 there is the key, which sets the date to the epoch
d.setUTCSeconds(utcSeconds);
```

Take a look at http://dygraphs.com/data.html and scroll to Array (native format)

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
data_for_dygraph = $.map(data_from_json, function(n) {
              return [ [ new Date(n[0]), n[1] ] ];
          });
```

where data_from_json are in format [ [ timestamp, y-value ], [ ts, t-val ], ...]

then use data_for_dygraph as a source of data form dygraph:

Comment: This is wrong, you need to multiply the timestamp integer with 1000 to get it right: Date(n[0]*1000)